# Adminhtml grid filtering with mass actions

Tags: adminhtml, ce-1.6.2.0, grid

I'm having some problems when using a mass action when a filter is applied to a grid block...

After a user has tried the mass action with the filter applied (once or twice) the mass action begins to work?!

When no filter is applied to the grid the mass actions work as expected..

Mage v1.6.2, All Caches off with Dev mode on..

Any help or tips appreciated

Below is my grid block `app/code/local/NS/Swatchrequest/Block/Adminhtml/Swatchrequest/Grid.php` or [Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/bennoislost/484b8c36e80977809c1b)

further below are the controller actions updateMassAction + deleteMassAction

EDIT: see layout xml right at the bottom

Ben

```
/**
 * Class Group path for Resource Collection
 */
const RESOURCE_COLLECTION = 'baddass_swatchrequest/swatchrequest_collection';

/**
 * Prepare base grid
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->setId('baddass_swatchrequest_swatchrequest');
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');

    /**
     * @TODO: Why??
     */
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);

    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

/**
 * Grid URL for AJAX request
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
}

/**
 * Assign Swatchrequest collection to grid block
 *
 * @return this
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    /**
     * @var Baddass_Swatchrequest_Model_Resource_Swatchrequest_Collection
     */
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(self::RESOURCE_COLLECTION);
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * Required to filter collection
 *
 * @TODO: really?
 * @param $column
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
}

/**
 * From Collection define columns and Export types
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => $this->__('ID'),
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'sortable' => true,
        'width' => '60px'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Customer Email'),
        'index' => 'email',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Created'),
        'type' =>'datetime',
        'index' => 'created_at'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Customer Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('product_name', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Product Name'),
        'index' => 'product_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('address', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Address Name'),
        'index' => 'address',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Status'),
        'width' => '120',
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'delivered_status',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options'   => array(
            0 => $this->__('Not Delivered'),
            1 => $this->__('Delivered')
        ),
        'frame_callback' => array(
            $this, 'decorateStatus'
        )
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', $this->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', $this->__('XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('swatchrequests');

    // delete en mass
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
        'label' => $this->__('Delete'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/deleteMass'),
        'confirm' => $this->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    // update delivered status en mass
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
        'label' => $this->__('Delivery Status'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/updateMass'),
        'additional' => array(
            'visibility' => array(
                'name' => 'delivered_status',
                'type' => 'select',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'label' => $this->__('Status'),
                'values' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Not Delivered',
                        'value' => 0
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Delivered',
                        'value' => 1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));

    return parent::_prepareMassaction();
}

/**
 * Get editable URL
 *
 * @param $row      Row in collection
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'id' => $row->getId()
    ));
}

/**
 * Decorate Delivery Status column with a Badge
 *
 * @param $value    Value for $row
 * @param $row      Row in collection
 * @param $column
 * @param $isExport
 * @return string
 */
public function decorateStatus($value, $row, $column, $isExport)
{
    $cell = '<span class="grid-severity-critical"><span>' . $value . '</span></span>';

    if($row->getDeliveredStatus() == 1) {
        $cell = '<span class="grid-severity-notice"><span>' . $value . '</span></span>';
    }

    return $cell;
}
```

controller actions...

```
public function deleteMassAction()
{
    if($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('swatchrequests')) {
        $deleted = array();

        $model = Mage::getModel('baddass_swatchrequest/swatchrequest');

        foreach((array) $data as $id) {
            $model->setId($id)->delete();
            $deleted[] = $id;
        }

        $this
            ->_getSession()
            ->addSuccess($this->__("Deleted Swatch Requests with ID's %s", implode(',', $deleted)));
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function updateMassAction()
{
    if($records = $this->getRequest()->getPost('swatchrequests')) {

        $delivered_status = (int) $this->getRequest()->getPost('delivered_status');
        $model = Mage::getModel('baddass_swatchrequest/swatchrequest');

        try {
            foreach((array) $records as $id) {
                $model->load($id);
                $model->setDeliveredStatus($delivered_status);
                $model->save();
            }

            $this
                ->_getSession()
                ->addSuccess($this->__('%s Swatch Requests updated', count($records)));
        }
        catch(Mage_Core_Model_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $this
                ->_getSession()
                ->addException($e, $this->__('An error occurred while updating the product(s) status.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_swatchrequest_list>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="baddass_swatchrequest/adminhtml_swatchrequest" name="swatchrequest"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_swatchrequest_list>
    <adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
        <block type="baddass_swatchrequest/adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid" name="ajax_grid" output="toHtml"/>
    </adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
    <adminhtml_swatchrequest_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="baddass_swatchrequest/adminhtml_swatchrequest_edit" name="baddass_swatchrequest_edit" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_swatchrequest_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the controller actions for         `deleteMass` and `updateMass`

Comment: updated the post. cheers.

Comment: "After a user has tried the mass action with the filter applied (once or twice) the mass action begins to work?!

When no filter is applied to the grid the mass actions work as expected.." - What exactly is your problem?

Comment: First try this one: remove `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);` from your grid constructor. If you don't use the grid somewhere else this is not really useful. If that doesn't work please post the layout section for the grid action. I mean the xml layout for `<adminhtml_..._swatchrequest_grid>` or however you defined it.

Comment: Hi Marius, I removed `$this->setSaveParamatersInSession(true)` from my grid `_construct()` method with the following results...

the delete and update mass actions worked without a filter applied.

when a filter was applied (to any column) none of the mass actions worked an re-directed to the adminhtml dashboard, where as before if a filter was applied on the second++ attempt a mass action would work.. seems like the form data was being stored in the session?!

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I wanted to say `$this->setUseAjax(true);` is kind useless if you don't use the grid somewhere else. `$this->setSaveParamatersInSession(true)` is actually useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the layout file (at least it was for me some time ago, that's why I asked for the layout code). Mainly this:

```
<adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
    <block type="baddass_swatchrequest/adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid" name="ajax_grid" output="toHtml"/>
</adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
```

The block should have a wrapper around it.

```
<adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="baddass_swatchrequest/adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid" name="ajax_grid"/>
    </block>
  </adminhtml_swatchrequest_grid>
```

This allows Magento to add the block that contains the form_key to the response of the ajax request. The `form_key` is required for all POST requests. That's why the mass action didn't work after filtering, because you didn't have anymore the `form_key`.
You can also put back `$this->setSaveParamatersInSession(true)` (I realized is not relevant. I wanted to refer to `$this->setUseAjax(true);`. Stupid mistake. Sorry.)

Comment: hi marius, that had no effect on the outcome :( I had to change my `_construct` method to `__construct` but when a filter is applied it redirects to the dashboard on the first attempt still. thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try also to revmove `$this->setUseAjax(true);` or to set this to `$this->setUseAjax(false);`. Also make sure you clear the cache after changing the layout file.

Comment: that seemed to do the trick! i removed the `getGridUrl()` method from Grid.php along with your recommendations. thank you for your help!

Do you know why `setUseAjax(true)` is an issue? It seems to work fine in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`?

Comment: Actually `setUseAjax` is not an issue. For some reason it does not work for you. Magento uses a `form_key` parameter for all POST requests to avoid CSRF. In your case, after the first ajax filter this form key was lost. That's why you get redirected to the dashboard and that's why I recommended changing the layout...so Magento will be able to insert the form_key block in the ajax response. But for some reason it didn't work for you. I don't know why.

Comment: thanks again. have you got any resources you could share to get filtering with `setUseAjax`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any. Just look at how the Magento core grids work with `setUseAjax`.