# After reset filter or search in grid searlizer. I am not able to do mass actions. Alert is coming with message "Please select the items"

Tags: admin, grid, grid-serlization

After reset filter in admin grid. Mass actions are not working. I am getting an alert message.
[image: Admin Grid Issue]

Comment: Found answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/adminhtml-grid-filtering-with-mass-actions. Yet to check.

Comment: above solution is not working. Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a tag in adminhtml layout section. So, it was causing the error.

```
<example_adminhtml_subsection_example>
       <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
           <block type="example/adminhtml_subsections_examplegrid" name="example.grid"/>
           <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="grid_serializer">
               <reference name="grid_serializer">
                   <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                       <grid_block_name>example.grid</grid_block_name>
                       <data_callback>getSelectedexample</data_callback>
                       <hidden_input_name>example</hidden_input_name>
                       <reload_param_name>example</reload_param_name>
                   </action>                 
               </reference>
           </block>
       </block>
   </example_adminhtml_subsection_example>
```

I missed below part of the section

```
   <example_adminhtml_subsection_examplegrid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="example/adminhtml_subsections_examplegrid" name="example.grid"/>
        </block>
    </example_adminhtml_subsection_examplegrid>
```